# D3 canvas animated path or line graph

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, html5-canvas

I Looking at code samples for D3.js to animate a line graph of 60K points, I am only able to find ones using svg. With using stroke I have to wait until all of the data has come in. How can I draw the graph as the points arrive from a text file stream.

[image]

Comment: You could use line segments connecting each pair of consecutive points instead of a single line for everything.

Comment: that doesn't seem to work actually.

Comment: In principle it should. Can't tell you anything else without seeing the code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Jag/1499/ you will need to edit j < 1000 to 10000

Comment: That seems to work fine as-is: https://jsfiddle.net/Q5Jag/1502/

Comment: So you added a delay with setTimeout. Awesome thanks!

Comment: So was this your question? I understand that your data points are arriving at different times anyway?

Comment: Yea that was it, you slowed it down so I can see the drawing happen. I wasn't expecting it draw so fast as to have it happen instantaneously with no delay. In use these points will be streaming from a server.